# Linux - replace a string

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I need to replace a string / line for each instance of that  string / line.
In the following line:

```
set output "/DS/tmp/2.gnuplot.ps"
```

I need it to be:

```
set output "./gnuplot.ps"
```

I want to use:

```
grep -rl 'stringONE' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/stringONE/stringTWO/g'
```

but when I try to use it, it has a conflict with the / in the string...

```
grep -rl '/DS/tmp/2.gnuplot.ps' ./ | xargs sed -i 's//DS/tmp/2.gnuplot.ps/./gnuplot.ps/g'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string to be replaced contains slash (/) then you can delimit arguments of sed's s command with something else, in this case I used comma:

```
grep -rl '/DS/tmp/2.gnuplot.ps' ./|xargs sed -i 's,/DS/tmp/2.gnuplot.ps,./gnuplot.ps,g'
```